# Delete file type in python in folder and all subfolders

Tags: python

I am writing s script in Python that requires a clean up to run at the end. What I need to do is delete any file that is a .ZIP

I have achieved this on the first folder using the following script.

```
print("Deleting all .ZIP files")
dir_name =  os.path.expanduser("~") + "/AWSSplunk/Downloads/"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".zip"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item))
print("Deleting .ZIP files completed")
```

However I also need to delete these .ZIP files in other sub directories - how can I get it to step through  the sub directories in this location removing these files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find files in multilevel subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533849/how-to-find-files-in-multilevel-subdirectories)

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt, the referenced answer is good but quite outdated. You can use [pathlib.Path.glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) with the pattern "**/*.zip" to find files.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `glob` module:

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob("**/*.zip", recursive=True):
    # delete file
```

Comment: Could even use `pathlib` for a more modern take (plus Path.glob is recursive by default)

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the files in a directory using `os.walk`:

```
import os

your_list = list(os.walk('your_folder'))
```